# Style a Button to look like an EditText (but still behave like a Button)

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-button

I realize this is sort of a weird thing to be doing, but I have a button that needs to *look* like an EditText but still behave like a button. My layout XML currently looks like this:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="?android:attr/editTextStyle" />
```

That gives it the appearance of an EditText, but also messes with the behavior a little bit by preventing the onClick event from being fired unless the button has focus (effectively making it require two clicks). Is there any way to keep the style without changing the button's behavior?

I thought about just making a nine-patch background that looks like an EditText, but with so many different Android versions and skins out there I'd rather use the system style if it's possible.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

How about an EditText that behaves like a button?

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/Edit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:clickable="true"/>
```

You can define an OnClickListener for it too. And it won't get focus.

Comment: I'd go for this if it were me.

Comment: Thanks, had the same need... thats what i call "outside the box".

Comment: This is very bad for accessibility, users who are blind or have impaired vision need to buttons to actually be buttons so they can properly navigate and use the control using a text reader like Talkback.

Answer (score 1):

If it absolutely needs to be a button, you can add a focus listener to your button that fires the onclick when the button receives focus.

```
weirdoButton.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

  @Override
  public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
    if(hasFocus) {
      weirdoButton.performClick();
    }
  }
});
```

The downside is that the click will fire when the button receives focus via a trackball or d-pad. Make it un-focus-able in the layout file:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/weirdoButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:focusable="false"
    style="?android:attr/editTextStyle" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer does let you style EditText as a button, but I found a discrepancy in it; when you long press on it, it lets you paste text into it which is terrible in terms of UX.

This is what I applied instead to style it as an EditText.

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:id="@+id/btnAddMember"
    style="?android:attr/editTextStyle"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:hint="Button Content"/>
```